# Haystack: Make query from one project to another

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using **Haystack 2.3.0** in some projects and everything is as expected (at least for now ).

Let's say I have **project1** and **project2**:

- Is there a simple way to make a query from **project1** to **project2** without adding new database to **Haystack** ?
- Is possible to **modify the SearchQuerySet *URL*** or something similar ?
- Should I simply use **urllib2** and make queries using only **ElasticSearch** ?
- If I add the `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` in **project1** pointing to **project2**, the queries from **project1** will be made on **project2** index ?

---

**project2** settings.py:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'project2.search_backends.CustomElasticSearchEngine',
        'URL': '127.0.0.1:9200',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

**Let's say external IP for project2 is `123.123.123.123`**

If I add in **project1** settings.py:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'project1.search_backends.CustomElasticSearchEngine',
        'URL': '123.123.123.123:9200',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

- Should this work if **project2** allow queries from external ip's ???

---

My concern about this method is that I don't want to modify the index of **project2** by mistake when querying from **project1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved adding the **project2** url to **project1** `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS`

Let's supose as in the question that **project2** url = `123.123.123.123`, I've configured my **project1** settings.py as:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'project1.search_backends.CustomElasticSearchEngine',
        'URL': '123.123.123.123:9200',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

With this all the querys made from **project1** are sent to Haystack/ElasticSearch in the **project2**